# Error sending emails from PHP with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I need your help! I have a code in PHP for sending emails (PHPMailer version 5.2.7). Send email from PHP, I use this method usually. 
I explain me...

The mails sent go directly to SPAM folder  to Hotmail, Gmail...

I have my own server with two domains (unique IP for two domains). In the domain1 the mails sent correctly (PHPMailer 5.2.7) and go directly to de inbox folder. In the domain2 the mails sent correctly but mails go directly to SPAM folder (PHPMailer 5.2.7)!!

Which is the difference between domain1 and domain2?? Have the same ip...
I can do mailings to domain2 not reach the spam folder?

P.D.: Shipping method in PHPMailer is SMTP with user and pass verified.

Comment: I have sometimes similar problem but don't know if it's Phpmailer problem or settings of target email's server. Hope someone will know

Comment: Mailing on your own is very tricky. I can assure you that the server side app is not a problem. Focus rather on the questions like: 1. Is the IP really unique for domain2? 2. Is domain2 on some blacklist? 3. Have you warmed up the IP?

Comment: Yes, is an unique Ip and Ip no appear in a blacklist

Comment: rectified, since the two domains comes to spam...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple factors that results in mail getting routed to spam folder. I don't think, it is anything to do with PHPmailer.  It is something to do with your IP reputation, complaints, activity, user engagement and some other factors.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be, that your mail server uses only one ip to send from.
Maybe the the reverse lookup from that ip resolves to your domain1.

Also related are dkim and spf records.